# C++ multiple instanced structs that can be called from other classes

Tags: c++, struct, extern

I want to make multiple structs, with different settings...! They all hold the same variables (same names etc)! But different implementations! And this settings should be reachable from another class... is this the best way? or am i doing something totally wrong?

**A.h:**

```
class A
{
};

struct Color{
   unsigned char r;
   unsigned char g;
   unsigned char b;
};

extern struct Settings settings;
```

**A.cpp**

```
struct settings{
   Color firstcolor = {0,0,0}; //error: data member initializer is not allowed
   Color secondcolor = {255,255,255}; //error: data member initializer is not allowed
};
struct anothersettings{
   Color firstcolor = {255,255,255}; //error: data member initializer is not allowed
   Color secondcolor = {0,0,0}; //error: data member initializer is not allowed
};
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
dosomethingwith(settings);
```

Comment: This looks good to me. I think it's the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're getting confused between a `struct` type and objects of that type. The whole point of a `struct` is that it describes the way objects of that type will look. If you're creating two `struct`s with exactly the same members (as you have done with `settings` and `anothersettings`), you're probably making a big mistake. Instead, you should have a single `struct` and then multiple objects of that type.

You'd be much better off having a single `struct Settings` like so:

```
struct Settings {
  Color firstcolor;
  Color secondcolor;
};
```

And then you can create objects of this type, setting the colors as appropriate:

```
Settings settings1;
settings1.firstcolor.r = 0;
settings1.firstcolor.g = 0;
// And so on...

Settings settings2;
settings2.firstcolor.r = 255;
settings2.firstcolor.g = 255;
// And so on...
```

In fact, there's a much nicer way to write this using aggregate initialization:

```
Settings settings1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {255, 255, 255}};
Settings settings2 = {{255, 255, 255}, {0, 0, 0}};
```

Then you can have a function that takes a `Settings` argument:

```
void soSomething(Settings);
```

Which you can then call like so:

```
doSomething(settings1);
// or
doSomething(settings2);
```

Comment: Oh indeed, that's the way to go...! i got confused big time yeah :'(
thanks :D

but settings1.firstcolor = {255,255,255}; doesnt work... how come?

Comment: says: settings1:"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier"

Comment: @SebastiaanvanDorst Did you give the definition of `struct Settings`?

Comment: yea i did.. tried "Settings settings1;" / "struct Settings settings1" all those... and then after "settings1." (and he doesn't even give me the option to fill .firstcolor after it...)

Comment: @SebastiaanvanDorst Something is wrong with your definition of `Settings`. Are you sure you have it? And no `Settings settings1;` is not the definition of `Settings`. I'm talking about the bit of code that looks like `struct Settings { ... };`.